# Group Elements by Each in Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

In Ruby, how would I group elements in an array until I find a different element? For example:

```
array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2]
```

I'd like to iterate through it, but up until the next element is different. I don't want to sort it because it still needs to be in that order. So if I were going through this array:

```
for [1, 1] do X  
for [2] do Y  
for [3, 3] do Z  
for [1] do X
```

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear; it doesn't seem like `group_by` does what you need. Can't you just iterate, store the previous value, and do whatever it is you're supposed to, until the current value isn't the same as the previous one?

Comment: @DaveNewton `group_by` will not work. The thing is, I'd like to do something to the group, not for each one. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way :

```
array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2]
array.group_by(&:itself).values
# => [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [6]]
```

Look [`#itself`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-itself) method.

If you have not asked above, then [`#slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) is your way to go :

```
array.slice_when { |i,j|  i != j }.to_a
# => [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [1], [5], [6], [2]]
array.slice_when { |i,j|  i != j }.each { |n| p "do_something_with_#{n}" }
# "do_something_with_[1, 1]"
# "do_something_with_[2]"
# "do_something_with_[3, 3]"
# "do_something_with_[1]"
# "do_something_with_[5]"
# "do_something_with_[6]"
# "do_something_with_[2]"
```

Comment: @bluexuemei what you mean that this code doesn't work. Do you see some error or you receive unexpected result? Please be more clear.

Comment: undefined method `itself' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: @bluexuemei what is your ruby version ?